# Geyser Plugin Behaviour for Closed Accounts

Tags: geyser

When I call the getAccountInfo web3 method for an account on which a CloseAccount instruction has been run, it returns null. I wanted to ask if the Geyser plugin notifies about an account update when a closed account instruction is run for it? Essentially, I want to know if an account was closed from Geyser plugin data.

Comment: Great question, I'm wondering myself too. Have you tried running a `solana-test-validator` with the Geyser plugin? You could close an account there and see what message you receive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should see an update for the address to an account owned by the system program, with no data and a zero lamports balance

Comment: If you were tracking accounts by owner what would be the best way to catch these events then? And why is it that it reverts to system program owned?

Comment: new questions don't belong in the replies to a year old answer

Answer (score 1):

This is merely a guess, but I would bet that:

- yes, you will receive an account update for such an account, when it is closed
- you will be able to infer that it has been closed because its new `lamports` balance is zero.