# Geyser closed account notifications

Tags: account, websocket, geyser

When an account is closed, the notification that comes from the geyser plugins `account_update` method includes the account with owner set to System Program - regardless of who the owner was before it was closed (see [here](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/825/geyser-plugin-behaviour-for-closed-accounts/1036)). This is unexpected for most devs, and those who know the behavior have to create subpar workarounds to catch these notifications.

My questions are,

1. Why is it like this?
2. How reasonable would it be to change this behavior?